# Replace integers in a string using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, string, replace, integer

I am trying to replace integers in a string using Visual Basic and can't seem to get it just right.

This is what I currently have:

```
lblNewPassword.Text = txtOrigPassword.Text.Replace("[0-9]", "Z")
```

I have also tried:

```
lblNewPassword.Text = txtOrigPassword.Text.Replace("#", "Z")
```

And:

```
lblNewPassword.Text = txtOrigPassword.Text.Replace("*#*", "Z")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a regex object like this:

**C#**

```
string input = "This is t3xt with n4mb3rs.";
Regex rgx = new Regex("[0-9]");
string result = rgx.Replace(input, "Z");
```

**VB**

```
Dim input As String = "This is t3xt with n4mb3rs." 
Dim rgx As New Regex("[0-9]")
Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(input, "Z")
```

**Update**: if then you want to change vowels by `X` you can add:

```
rgx As New Regex("[A-Za-z]")
result = rgx.Replace(result, "X")
```

Comment: Excellent! Where would I add additional conditions to replace such as all vowels with "X"?

Comment: @jsnaredude you can clone both the Regex and .Replace line and change the `[0-9]` by `[A-Za-z]` also modify `z` by `x`

Comment: Sorry I should have made that more clear. I would be doing the replace for numbers and vowels on the same string. In this case I would apply both to the string 'result'.

Comment: Superb! Thanks for helping a newbie out.